# should I make use a 'synchronized' version for the collections message in the 'onMessage'.?

Tags: java, jms

if there are say some large number of messages in the JMS queue, and I only have a single listener, is there some way to have the listener create threads to handle multiple messages at once?

`OnMessage` will pick only one message at a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message listener has one entry point, onMessage that a messaging provider invokes when it has to deliver a message. At any point messaging provider will invoke the onMessage with just one message and does not deliver another message till the onMessage method returns. So it does not help if you create multiple threads in the listener.

You need to create multiple listeners to receive messages in parallel.